# Ask: How to display 3 table data into 1 table?

Tags: php, sql

Example:

```
Table A
Name
Stock

Table B
Name
Stock

Table C
Name
Stock
```

Result it should be:

```
A.name|A.stock
B.name|B.stock
C.name|C.stock
```

What should be the sql command?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT NAME,STOCK FROM TABLE_A
    UNION ALL
 SELECT NAME,STOCK FROM TABLE_B
    UNION ALL
 SELECT NAME,STOCK FROM TABLE_C
```

Comment: what if stock is grater than 10?

Comment: Sorry. Could you please explain what the problem with such stock is ?

Comment: stock is the quantity of the product, i want to display the data with the stock less than 10

Comment: SELECT NAME,STOCK FROM TABLE_A where stock<10
    UNION ALL
 SELECT NAME,STOCK FROM TABLE_B where stock<10
    UNION ALL
 SELECT NAME,STOCK FROM TABLE_C where stock<10

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the tables have the same number of columns and same datatypes just union them

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table_A
 UNION
SELECT * 
  FROM Table_B
 UNION
SELECT * 
  FROM Table_C
```

Answer (score -1):

see the link below about command union

#### The SQL UNION Operator

The `UNION` operator is used to combine the result-set of two or more `SELECT` statements.

Each `SELECT` statement within `UNION` must have the same number of columns
The columns must also have similar data types
The columns in each `SELECT` statement must also be in the same order

```
UNION Syntax
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1
UNION
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table2;
```

#### UNION ALL Syntax

The `UNION` operator selects only distinct values by default. To allow duplicate
values, use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table2;
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp